# Does killing villagers in Bedrock Edition have negative consequences?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

I recently tried to build a simple iron farm in Bedrock Edition using [this tutorial from silentwisperer](https://youtu.be/P2Fm9Np0zgk), but apparently I built it too close to the village I started for my own little compound because now I have a massive overpopulation of villagers and iron golems are spawning all over the place - at last count there were six iron golems roaming around between my village and the now mostly useless iron farm. (***NOTE:** I've since rebuilt the same iron farm design further away, and it seems to work correctly, albeit with a very low rate of return*).

Anyway, now I'm trying to build a separate [villager trading hall](https://youtu.be/RCqNZOGiG_A) (*credit to [Avomance](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCeprnLp3l8oZPAig8XjVLnA)*) and all these stupid villagers keep "stealing" the job site blocks so my merchants can't restock their trades or get appropriate professions (*I **really** need to get a librarian with Mending*). I intend to tear down the improperly located iron farm and I'm about to go on a Minecraft villager murder spree, but before I start dealing swift death to a bunch of villagers, I wanted to find out if I'm going to be dealing with any fallout afterward.

I've read/heard stuff about a gossip system for villagers in Minecraft, but everything I've seen so far seems to indicate this is only implemented (currently) in the Java Edition. Are there negative consequences to killing villagers in Bedrock Edition, or can I just start hacking away at them? Should I instead try to bring up some lava from my mining operation underground and try to push villagers into a little lava lake?

**UPDATE:** According to the [Minecraft Wiki for Villager](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Villager), while the coming together and meeting for gossip is apparently common to all versions:

> The reputation mechanic however is only present in the Java Edition.

I'm still not certain whether or not a diamond- and sweet berry-fueled rampage is
advisable, or if I should consider alternate means for euthanizing an entire village population.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, there are no consequences, unless you are not in peaceful mode, where the iron golem will try to kill you.

Answer (score 2):

no, there are consequences, if you want to trade with the villagers don't kill them. it'll make the trade a lot more expensive. so don't kill them if you want to trade

Answer (score 0):

Villagers gossip. If there is a naturally spawned golem, it will hunt you down

Comment: There's already an (old) accepted answer saying the exact same thing